# oracle: числа с заданным количеством значащих цифр

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Требуется преобразовать произвольные числа к числам с заданным количеством значащих цифр. Например, если нужны две значащие цифры, то результаты ожидаются такие:

```
123456789   -> 120000000
123         -> 120
1.23        -> 1.2
0.123456789 -> 0.12
0.0012345   -> 0.0012
1           -> 1.0 или 1
0.001       -> 0.0010 или 0.001
```

Есть ли способы это реализовать более элегантные, чем, например, такой:

```
to_number(to_char(some_number, '9.9EEEE'), '9.9EEEE')
```

Comment: Обычно такая задача делается не на сервере СУБД, не на sql, а на клиенте на языках высокого уровня,  как правило на php/c++/c#. На с# это звучит где-то так `string.Format("{0:0,00}",rd["some_number"])`. Моё мнение -  сервер базы не грузят "клиентскими" задачами.

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо за комментарий, если придётся столкнуться с c#, буду иметь в виду. Но сейчас требуется решение средствами БД.

Comment: Уточните - нужно выполнять округление при получении данных в запросе, или необходимо изменить сами данные в таблице?

Comment: @Akina в основном при получении данных и их обработке (в т.ч. в pl/sql-коде). Это что-то принципиально меняет?

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin Что то я сомневаюсь что есть что то более элегантное. То что вы привели очень даже ничего для такой задачи

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin Конечно, меняет. Раз речь идёт о том, что надо изменить ОТОБРАЖЕНИЕ полученных данных, то следует поручить решение этой задачи клиенту, а не выкручивать руки серверу.